# Android - Need help for Tabs+Swipe template in SDK 20

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I really like the template for Tabs+Swipe. You know...this one:

[image]

The problem is, **I do not know where to start** after creating that template. **How to put a layout into each tab page?**

Can we do something like call a Class when the tab is selected? So I can store the view for first tab in Class A then second tab in Class B.

I cannot found any information about this in Google, maybe because it is a new feature from Android SDK?

Thanks

Comment: If you have downloaded the android support library from sdk manager then \android-sdks\extras\android\support\samples\Support4Demos\src\com\example\android\supportv4\app\FragmentTabsPager.java provide a good example on how to do that

Comment: @SreejithKrishnanR I downloaded that and import it to my workspace. But I got like 800 errors, mostly `cannot be resolved` error. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I solved this issue by doing following  1.Right click imported project - Properties - Android - Project Build Target and setting android 4.1 as build target. 2.After that cleaning the project (Project - Clean) fixed all errors in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to put a layout into each tab page?

The generated code creates a `ViewPager` in the layout file and wires up action bar tabs to the pages in that `ViewPager`. Personally I'd rather use a `PagerTabStrip`, or possibly one of the ViewPagerIndicator equivalents, but they didn't ask me... :-)

Regardless, to fill in the pages, you need to replace (or complete) the `SectionsPagerAdapter` and/or `DummySectionFragment` inner classes of the generated activity. Right now, this is set up to have three pages, each of which is merely a `TextView`. But, you could have `DummySectionFragment` inflate a layout instead, and if you are looking for different layouts per tab, you would probably create separate `Fragment` implementations per layout/tab combination. You would then teach `SectionsPagerAdapter` how many pages you want (`getCount()`) and what to use for each page (`getItem()`) and what each tab caption is (`getPageTitle()`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I create a test.xml containing a button. Then I change the code of `onCreateView()` inside `DummySectionFragment` into 


`View view = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.test, container);
return view;`

But it crashed the template, any idea?

Comment: @DarcCode: AFAIK, `getLayoutInflater()` does not take a parameter, so that code should not even compile. Your `onCreateView()` is *passed* a `LayoutInflater` -- use that one. Beyond that, look at your stack trace in LogCat.

Comment: I changed the getLayoutInflater() to the passed LayoutInflater parameter. But it also crashed with this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` What's the meaning?

Comment: @DarcCode: Try `inflate(R.layout.test, container, false)`. Also, be sure that you are not reusing the same inflated `View` for multiple positions.

Comment: Wow adding `false` make it works. But all tab have same layout. So should I create 3 different class that `extends Fragment`? Then inside `getItem()` should I create IF statement like `if(i==1)`?

Comment: @DarcCode: "So should I create 3 different class that extends Fragment?" -- I cannot answer that, as is tied to your overall application logic and architecture. If all tabs should have the same business logic, just with different data, then a single `Fragment` class should suffice. Just return different instances from `getItem()`. For example, see: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments

Comment: Thanks, +1 for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you can place an an example of activity switching between tabs?  The example above isn't ideal.

Comment: It is easier to use `Fragment` on tabs. Using `Activity` on tab is quite complicated and not recommended.

Comment: hmm ... is this meant as an answer? Sounds more like a comment or question for additional info?