# How can I allow horizontal tab navigation (swipe views) with action bar navigation tabs?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, swipeview

How can I allow [horizontal tab navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging) (swipe views) if I'm using action bar [navigation tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)?

[image]

Is there anything special I have to do to get this to work with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code-generated stuff for a "Tabs+Swipe" activity (from BlankActivity in the new activity wizard in Eclipse) has code for this. Basically, your tabs tie into a `ViewPager`, calling `setCurrentItem()` to change the page, rather than running their own `FragmentTransaction` or otherwise affecting the UI. The `ViewPager` handles the horizontal swiping, and you populate those pages using some form of `PagerAdapter` (one is code generated for you). See [this very related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355302/android-need-help-for-tabsswipe-template-in-sdk-20/12355483#12355483) for more.

> Is there anything special I have to do to get this to work with ActionBarSherlock?

Other than standard stuff for using ActionBarSherlock, nothing out of the ordinary should be required. `ViewPager` is in the Android Support package, which ActionBarSherlock also needs, so you will have that already in your project.

Note, though, that action bar tabs only sometimes show up as tabs. In some screen sizes and orientations, they are automatically converted into a drop-down list (per "list navigation" with the action bar instead of "tab navigation"). If you want to use tabs all of the time, rather than using action bar tabs with `ViewPager`, use `PagerTabStrip` (from the Android Support package) or a suitable indicator from [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  To clarify, if the tabs are converted to list navigation, will swipe navigation still work?  Or would that be "anachronistic", so to speak?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: "To clarify, if the tabs are converted to list navigation, will swipe navigation still work?" -- AFAIK, it should. I cannot imagine that changes to the depiction of "tabs" would somehow whack the `ViewPager`. "And how weird that the dupe and I both posted within a half hour! :)" -- ummmm... great minds think alike? :-)