# error in implementing horizontal swiping tab bar button in android application

Tags: android

I am making an android application in which I have to implement swiping tab bar .
I tried the sample code also.

This is my mail xml file :

http://pastebin.com/Z3fPnzv1

And this is my footer_tabs.xml file :

Now issue is that tabs are not swiping in this case

Thanks
Cool jatt

Comment: Please read your own question again and try to imagine that you don't know anything about your project. You should see that you aren't providing enough information at all. Besides the confusing sentences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is reference to some of the good topics, they will help you::

1. [Horizontal Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356238/how-can-i-allow-horizontal-tab-navigation-swipe-views-with-action-bar-navigati) Referral Question.
2. [Horizontal Tab Swipper](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/)
3. [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html)

Thanks.

Comment: @satish.,....let me check with links u provided.....if u have done this type of work,,,plz send me code

Comment: the second link Horizontal view swiping is an important user interface ... it is explained step by step try out that... i didn't do this before... Good luck with your battle buddy

Comment: The second one suits to the need, i think.